# PHP 7 Imagick writeimage() path issue

Tags: php, filepath, imagick

I'm trying to create a simple thumbnail image and upload to server using imagick. The image is being selected via a form and I am able to get the thumb created via Imagick, however it is not saving to the right location.

When I use the below code, the image saves to the same directory as the page the code is on and includes the file path within the image name. For example "\images\myuploaded.jpg" as the file name.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $errors = array();
    if(preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['image']['type'])){
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $imagethumb = new Imagick("$image");
        $imagethumb->setImageFormat("jpg");
        $imagethumb->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
        $imgpath = "\images\\".$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $imagethumb->writeImage($imgpath);
        $_SESSION['message']=$image;
    }else{
        $errors['image'] = "You must select a .png, .jpg, or .gif images file.";
        $_SESSION['message']=$errors['image'];
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help.

_t

Comment: `\\` has no special meaning on linux

Comment: Okay. How should I specify the path to the directory I want? I tried using "/images/name-of-image.jpg, but received an error. "Uncaught ImagickException: unable to open image `/images/nik-1.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2705"

Comment: That's because `/images/nik-1.jpg` is an absolute path. Do you have `images` created under the filesystem root `/`?

Comment: Thank you zerkms! Changing path to images/nik-1.jpg resolved the issue. Simple path and not Imagick.